# Ambari 2.2.0 error installing hadoop services

Tags: ambari

I am installing a complete new cluster using HDP 2.3

When Ambari tries to install the services (HDFS Client or Namenode) it errors out. below is the stderr

`stderr: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py", line 35, in <module> BeforeAnyHook().execute() File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 220, in execute method(env) File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py", line 26, in hook import params File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/params.py", line 187, in <module> hadoop_conf_dir = conf_select.get_hadoop_conf_dir(force_latest_on_upgrade=True) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/functions/conf_select.py", line 374, in get_hadoop_conf_dir select(stack_name, "hadoop", version) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/functions/conf_select.py", line 252, in select shell.checked_call(get_cmd("set-conf-dir", package, version), logoutput=False, quiet=False, sudo=True) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner result = function(command, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages**/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call raise Fail(err_msg) resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'conf-select set-conf-dir --package hadoop --stack-version 2.3.4.0-3485 --conf-version 0' returned 1. /usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop/conf does not exist Error: Error: Unable to run the custom hook script ['/usr/bin/python2', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py', 'ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/command-302.json', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/structured-out-302.json', 'INFO', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp']**`


`stdout: 2016-02-26 23:04:51,884 - The hadoop conf dir /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf exists, will call conf-select on it for version 2.3.4.0-3485 2016-02-26 23:04:51,885 - Checking if need to create versioned conf dir /etc/hadoop/2.3.4.0-3485/0 2016-02-26 23:04:51,885 - call['conf-select create-conf-dir --package hadoop --stack-version 2.3.4.0-3485 --conf-version 0'] {'logoutput': False, 'sudo': True, 'quiet': False, 'stderr': -1} 2016-02-26 23:04:51,928 - call returned (1, '/etc/hadoop/2.3.4.0-3485/0 exist already', '') 2016-02-26 23:04:51,929 - checked_call['conf-select set-conf-dir --package hadoop --stack-version 2.3.4.0-3485 --conf-version 0'] {'logoutput': False, 'sudo': True, 'quiet': False} Error: Error: Unable to run the custom hook script ['/usr/bin/python2', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py', 'ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/command-302.json', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/structured-out-302.json', 'INFO', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp']`

Comment: That output is hard to read, perhaps you can clean it up a little so it's easier for people to help you?

Answer (score -2):

The answer is in the error log, highlighting it for you:

> Execution of 'conf-select set-conf-dir --package hadoop
>
> --stack-version 2.3.4.0-3485 --conf-version 0' returned 1
>
> /usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop/conf does not exist

Fix your configuration and it will start to work.

Comment: yup I already did that and it gave an error on another directory missing. Shouldn't the install process itself be creating these directories?